# naming columns in lapply

Tags: r, names

Consider

```
a1<-data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(3,4))
a2<-data.frame(a=c(5,6),b=c(7,8))
```

I want to rename the columns to j and k.

I did

```
lapply(list(a1,a2),function(ct){names(ct)<-c("j","k")})
```

but the old column names, a and b, persist. Can someone help?

Comment: return the dataframe back after changing names, `lapply(list(a1,a2),function(ct){names(ct)<-c("j","k");ct})`

Comment: @Ronak Shah  The column names persist. Please try names(a1) after you run your statement.

Comment: @Ronak Shah I understand. This is pass-by-value. So I have to capture the results in a variable again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only two such dataframes, we can directly do :

```
names(a1) <- c("j","k")
names(a2) <- c("j","k")
```

If we have multiple such dataframes, we can do get them in a list using `mget`, change the names with `lapply` and then use `list2env` to get them in global environment.

```
listdf <- lapply(mget(paste0("a", 1:2)), function(ct) {names(ct)<-c("j","k");ct})
list2env(listdf, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: What is the significance of list2env(listdf, .GlobalEnv)?

Comment: `listdf` has all the dataframes in a list. `list2env` makes them as separate dataframes based on their names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setNames` and `assign` to name columns with `lapply`:

```
invisible(lapply(c("a1", "a2"), function(ct) assign(ct,
   setNames(get(ct), c("j","k")), envir=.GlobalEnv)))
names(a1)
#[1] "j" "k"
names(a2)
#[1] "j" "k"
```

But it might be easier to use a *for loop* like:

```
for(ct in c("a1", "a2")) assign(ct, setNames(get(ct), c("j","k")))
```